# Interpreting a classification tree

Tags: classification, cart

I am currently trying to understand how I should interpret my classification tree. This is mine : [image]

How can I know which group most likely to swipe left, the probability of swiping left and the percentage of the sample belonging to this group?

and

How can I know which group most likely to swipe right, the probability of swiping right and the percentage of the sample belonging to this group?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like each box has three things, from top to bottom 1) the most likely action, 2) the probability of swiping right, 3) the percent of individuals in that group. Note that children in the tree are "contained" in their parent, so that the 3) percent of individuals in the immediate children always add up to the parent percent. I.e. they're not distinct groups, they are subdivisions of the same group.

From this, the group most likely to swipe right is "not longterm/marriage, not male, not short-term". However, only 5% of users fall into this bin, so it might be difficult to generalize this result.  This is because if you take a tree far enough down, you can always find a group with 100% swipe right probability, but there's few individuals in it, and that high percentage is probably a random occurrence in your data rather than anything real. So the further down you go, and the fewer individuals in that group, the more grains of salt you need to take with that probability.